# CoffeeScript event not firing

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't know what to look at on this. I have a Rails 3.2.8 application, and I have a page where all of my Coffeescripts are firing except one.

My controller is called "apps", and my Coffeescript file is app.js.coffee. Here is a the call that is not firing:

```
$("#products_id").change ->
  alert "hello"
```

The item in my view renders as follows:

```
<select id="products_id" class="select required" name="products[id]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1368">015-0761</option>
  <option value="1752">030-237</option>
</select>
```

I am using Firefox and Firebug to debug. I have verified that the apps.js script is indeed loaded with my changes. I'm getting no activity on the select box when I choose different things.

I have also moved the call around inside the apps.js.coffee file, and I'm using TextMate to view the invisible characters to make sure I don't have any bad whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! That element doesn't exist when the page is rendered, it's displayed later. Therefore, I needed to change the call to this:

```
$("#products_id").live "change", ->
  alert "hello"
```

That works!

Comment: You should be using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) these days, the [`live` docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) show you how to switch to `on`.